# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL when using Twitter/Facebook

Tags: javascript, twitter, cross-domain, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am building a website using the Twitter and Facebook JavaScript SDKs.  I am attempting to perform tweets and facebook shares from the site.  But I am getting the following error when I try to send a tweet OR facebook share from my website:

Chrome:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://edro.no-ip.org:3000/#_=_ from frame with URL http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1354761327.html#_=1355186876357&count=none&id=twitter-widget-0&lang=en&original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fedro.no-ip.org%3A3000%2F%23_%3D_&related=xbox%3AGhostfire%20Games&size=m&text=Check%20out%20this%20fun%20story!%20%23atalltale&url=http%3A%2F%2Fedro.no-ip.org%3A3000%2Fstories%2FiqU9xW1FJI. The frame requesting access set 'document.domain' to 'twitter.com', but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set 'document.domain' to the same value to allow access.
```

Safari:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://edro.no-ip.org:3000/ from frame with URL http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.1354761327.html#_=1355197702032&count=none&id=twitter-widget-0&lang=en&original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fedro.no-ip.org%3A3000%2F&related=xbox%3AGhostfire%20Games&size=m&text=Check%20out%20this%20fun%20story!%20%23atalltale&url=http%3A%2F%2Fedro.no-ip.org%3A3000%2Fstories%2FiqU9xW1FJI. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

Here's the code (I only included the relevant parts):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>

<body>
</body>

<center>
    <h1><a href="/">Page Header</a></h1>
    &nbsp
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Once the Facebook SDK is fully loaded, this callback will be invoked
    window.fbAsyncInit = function()
    {
     FB.init({
      appId: "250634021702621",
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      channelUrl: '//edro.no-ip.org:3000/channel.html',
     });
     FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleStatusChange);
    };

    // Callback for once we are logged in and authorized
    function handleStatusChange(response) {
     document.body.className = response.authResponse ? 'connected' : 'not_connected';
     if (response.authResponse)
     {
     }
    };

    // Declare a generic SDK loading function
    var loadSDK = function(doc, script, id, src)
    {
     var js, fjs = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0];
     if (!doc.getElementById(id))
     { 
      js = doc.createElement(script);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = src;
      js.async = true;                      // Makes SDK load asynchronously
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
     }
    };

    // Twitter SDK loading
    loadSDK(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs', 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');

    // Facebook SDK loading
    loadSDK(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk', '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');

    // Facebook callback - useful for doing stuff after Facebook returns.  Passed as parameter to API calls later.
    var myResponse;
    function callback(response)
    {
     if (response)
     {
      // For debugging - can query myResponse via JavaScript console
      myResponse = response;
      if (response.post_id)
      {
      }
      else
      {
       // Else we are expecting a Response Body Object in JSON, so decode this
       var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.body);
       // If the Response Body includes an Error Object, handle the Error
       if(responseBody.error)
       {
       }
       // Else handle the data Object
       else
       {
       }
      }
     }
    }
    // All API calls go here
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {               

     // Post to your wall
     $('#post_wall').click(function ()
     {
      FB.ui(
       {
        method: 'feed',
        // useful if we want the callback to go to our site, rather than the JavaScript, so we can log an event
        redirect_uri: 'http://edro.no-ip.org:3000',
        link: 'http://edro.no-ip.org:3000/stories/{game.id}',
        picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
        name: 'name',
        caption: 'caption',
        description: 'description'
        // display: 'popup'
       },
       callback
      );
      return false;
     });
    });</script>

    <!-- Tweet code-->
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" data-lang="en" data-count="none" data-related="xbox:Ghostfire Games" data-text="test" data-url="http://edro.no-ip.org:3000/stories/iqU9xW1FJI" class="twitter-share-button">Tweet</a>

    <!-- Facebook share code-->
    <p id="msg"><a href="#" id="post_wall">Share on Facebook</a></p>
</center>

</html>
```

Comment: A careful read of the error will help greatly.  "Domains, protocols and ports must match."  The relevant part in that line is "ports".  You are talking over 3000.  I'm guessing that is what is messing things up.  A quick google search confirmed that others have that problem.  I'm not sure that you CAN use the Facebook API with a non-standard port.

Answer (score 0):

"Domains, protocols and ports must match."
Typical mismatch in (older versions of ?) Safari is http://www.example.com and http://example.com.